# POST parameters not available using nodemcu

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I've been trying to create a tiny webserver that can handle GET and POST methods.

For some reason it seems that POST parameters are not available to be parsed because whenever I print the whole request string they simply aren't there:

```
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
        local buf = ""
        local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
        if(method == nil)then
            _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
        end
        local _GET = {}
        if (vars ~= nil)then
            for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
                _GET[k] = v
                buf = buf , v
            end
       end
if method == "POST" then
    buf = "POST DETECTED"
    print("########")
    print(request)
    print("********")
end
client:send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
client:send("Server: NodeMCU 0.1\n")
client:send("Content-Length: " .. string.len(buf) .. "\n\n")
client:send(buf);
client:close();
collectgarbage();
end)
end)
```

For a simply curl call like the one in the following example:

```
 curl 10.0.130.12 -v -X POST -d "foo=bar"
```

What I see on the NodeMCU side is:

```
#########
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.130.12
User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


*********
```

Why can't I see the POST parameters?

Comment: If you're doing this because you want to learn about NodeMCU and/or Lua then good for you. If not, I suggest you try https://github.com/marcoskirsch/nodemcu-httpserver.

Comment: I get the expected output running your code on the 1.5.1 dev branch from nodemcu-build.com . Maybe you can try on that build and see if you continue to have issues?  `########
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.100
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar
********`

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers send the HTTP header and the POST data in a single packet (i.e. Firefox) and some break it up (i.e. Safari). You need to keep reading data until you've received however many bytes specified by Content-Length right after the header ends (that's the \r\n\r\n).

As pointed out by Marcel Stör, nodemcu-httpserver has the POST HTTP method functional, so you can use that as an example or straight up use the project directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the parameters are not printed in the output, as the `Content-Length: 7` clearly indicates that the content is sent as expected. If you want to see the POST data with curl, you need to add `--trace-ascii -`, which will show you something like the following in the output:

```
=> Send data, 7 bytes (0x7)
0000: foo=bar
```

To handle them in the script, you'd need to process the body of the request; the following code may give you the parameters to process: `local vars = string.match(request, "\r\n\r\n(.*)")`.